# Gmail Displayed HTML is shown with Tags, html is simple, no ccs and styles

Tags: html, gmail

This is my simple html with test content, that was sent in message body by mailing server to Gmail account:

```
<html> 
<body> 
Some text goes here
<br><br> 
User who applied: Username
<br> 
User's email: someone@some.com
</body> 
</html>
```

Gmail, on my hope, should be showing just formatted text without tags, because no mentioned in other topics restrictions (like css, styles, etc.) are here, but it doesn't.

What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: did you set headers??

Answer (score 0):

Gmail treats it as plain text or rich text ... It doesn't allows HTML templates as far as I know...
You should go to mailchimp to send HTML mail

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your settings? While creating the mail, you can send a header where you say to the gmail server: 'Watch out, this message is in HTML, no plain text'.

If you are sending your mail through php mail function, you can add the following header:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

If you are using something like RoundCube or Squirrlemail you can check it within your settings.